# Android Http Post is not reliable

Tags: java, android, http

From my app I am trying to make an HTTP request to a vps. When my written task executes completely, the post request works as intended. However, I am having issues making this work reliably. I have tried putting the code in an AsyncTask but this seem to often fail midway and not complete. I have also tried creating a JobService that launches an AsyncTask, however, this does not seem to work reliably either. Should I put the request code in the job service or is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Please include your include in a reproducible format.

Answer (score 0):

for one of my projects I have used volley library, it's really easy to use and it handles everything for you even async task. Look it up, here is a sample code :

```
String url = "http://url";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // success
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // error

    }
});
```

You can quickly add volley to your project by adding one line to the gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

You can find more informations on this link : https://developer.android.com/training/volley

Hope this helps you a little